# Evaluate $\int_{|z|=3}{\frac{9z^5}{(z-2)(1+2z)^2(1-3z)^3}}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$\displaystyle\int_{|z|=3}{\frac{9z^5}{(z-2)(1+2z)^2(1-3z)^3}}dz$

I tried evaluating this directly and it has turned into a nightmare of a problem. I was thinking this is more easily solved using the residue at infinity. Are my intuitions correct? If so I'm not really sure how to go about doing so.

Comment: What do you mean by the residue at infinity?

Comment: Res$_{z_0=\infty}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_0}{f(z)dz}$

Comment: Why do you want to evaluate at $z_0\to\infty$?

Comment: Okay clearly my intuitions where wrong. What is the best way to solve this...

Comment: It really isn't a nightmare to compute the residues at the finite poles, but sure, you can just do the infinite one and be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct. Note that
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) +\frac1{2\pi i}I=0$$ where $I$ is your integral that happens to include all poles.

Recall $$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z)=-\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$$

simplifying gives

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z) = -\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac1{z^2}\frac{9z}{(1-2z)(z+2)^2(z-3)^3}=-\frac9{1\cdot4\cdot (-27)}$$

Thus $$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z) =\frac1{12}$$ and $$I= -\frac{\pi i}{6}$$.